# Understanding difference between Initialization and Assignment in Kotlin Generics

Tags: kotlin

I was the reading the section about in and out keywords in Kotlin from the book "Kotlin Programming - Big Nerd Ranch Guide". I am coming from a C++ background where initialization and assignment are two very different concepts. The following code snippet from the book (slightly modified) is having me confsed.

The code is as below:

```
class Barrel<out T>(val item:T)
open class Loot(val value: Int)
class Fedora(val name:String, value:Int) : Loot(value)

public fun main(){
    var fedoraBarrel: Barrel<Fedora> = Barrel(Fedora("a generic-looking fedora", 15))
    var lootBarrel: Barrel<Loot> = fedoraBarrel
    lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel
    val myFedora: Fedora = lootBarrel.item
}
```

Here, when I comment out the line

```
lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel
```

I get the following error on the subsequent line where I am trying to retrieve a Fedora item from the Barrel and the error is

```
Error:(27, 28) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Loot but Fedora was expected
```

How is assigning a fedoraBarrel to lootBarrel different from initializing lootBarrel with a fedoraBarrel. Why do I need the line

```
lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel
```

for this code to compile?

Comment: That's not related to the `out` keyword. This is a smart cast, where lootBarrel becomes a  `Barrel<Fedora>`. Note that you can't get an item out of a `Barrel<Loot>`

Comment: Why is the smart cast applicable only when I have the line lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel? Why is the line var lootBarrel: Barrel<Loot> = fedoraBarrel meaningless?

Comment: I understand it is not related to out keyword which is why I changed the title. I mentioned it in the post incase someone wanted to refer to the book as this code snippet is from the book

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'can't get an item out of Barrel<Loot>'. I thought an out parameter indicated that we can only get things out (covariance) and not write things in contrary to what you are saying.

Comment: Regarding your last question you can drop the type when you initialize i.e. : `var lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel`

Comment: @DavidSoroko That defeats the point of the whole question because if I do that then the inferred type of lootBarrel would be Barrel<Fedora> and not Barrel<Loot> as I intend it to be

Comment: I meant that `Loot` does not have a field named `item`, a `Fedora` does.

Comment: @al3c No, `Fedora` doesn't either; `Barrel<Loot>` and `Barrel<Fedora>` both do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the line `var lootBarrel: Barrel<Loot> = fedoraBarrel` meaningless?

It isn't meaningless, just the contrary; you explicitly request the more general type, 
the compiler reasonably assumes that you *really* want `lootBarrel` to have type `Barrel<Loot>`, so `lootBarrel.item` has type `Loot`, not `Fedora`.

After

```
lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel
```

the compiler sees it's assigned a value of type `Barrel<Fedora>` so can be locally treated as having that type until it's changed.

Could it work without reassignment? Yes. It's discussed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13663, with the current conclusion

> I don't think it's possible to reasonably implement this request for all cases, and we'd need to devise a tricky algorithm to make it work at least in most cases

The comment before last gives a workaround, in your case

```
var lootBarrel: Barrel<Loot>
lootBarrel = fedoraBarrel
val myFedora: Fedora = lootBarrel.item
```

(note this is initialization, not assignment)

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your case to this code:

```
var a: Number = 0
a + 1 // Raises an error, class Number does not have `plus` function
a = 0
a + 1 // Works fine
```

When you initialize your variable (`var a: Number = 0`) compiler sets the type of `a` to `Number` regardless of the type of expression used as initial value (it does not cast `a` to `Int` because you specified the type explicitly).

When you write `a = 0`, smart cast happens, so you can work with `a` as with `Int` until you change `a` again.

Comment: Thank you so much. This cleared up a lot of things. I had to however accept the other answer. Thanks for your time.